# Why are cows (коровы) called "крупный рогатый скот" so frequently?

Tags: этимология, выражения

Why cows/bulls rarely called so, especially in official documents, but the term КРС (Крупный рогатый скот, lit. "large horned cattle") is used instead? Other farming animals are called simpler.

Почему коров/быков так часто называют КРС (Крупный рогатый скот), особенно в документах? Других сельскохозяйственных животных называют проще.

Comment: In English it is not "cows" but "cattle": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle

Comment: It's a bureaucratic formula to encompass all kinds of bovine, originated in the Tsarist-Imperial era.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересно, что слово "говядина" происходит от слова "говядо", которое означает "коровы, быки и волы". "Словарь русского языка XVIII в." дает такой [пример употребления](http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc/04/sl514909.htm):

> **ГОВЯ́ДО**, а, ср. Слав. Общее название быков и коров.
> Охотно лижут соль овцы, голуби, козы, лошади, и **говяда**.

В [словаре Ефремовой](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/154640/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE) это слово помечено как "местн." (правда не понятно где это "местное" употребление зафиксировано, но это в любом случае "диалектное, устаревшее" слово):

> Крупный рогатый скот (бык, вол, корова).

Есть это слово и в словаре Фасмера, и в словаре Даля. Примечательно что Даль в определении этого слова использует выражение "крупная рогатая скотина":

> ГОВЯДО
> ср., церк. крупная рогатая скотина, бык, вол или корова.

(Заметьте, что словари не упоминают здесь ни телок, ни бычков-кастратов, ни других специализированных с/х терминов)

Если верить сайту [dic.academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/225390), эта статья взята из редакции 1866 года, так что термин КРС имеет давнюю историю.

Почему же для коров и быков используют этот термин?

Скорее всего потому что другого слова для обозначения быков, коров и волов в русском языке нет (почему-то "говядо" не стало общеупотребимым словом), а другого "крупного рогатого скота" [в широком смысле](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_colier/4024/%D0%9A%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%9F%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%99) (зубры, бизоны, буйволы, яки) в сельском хозяйстве России не используют.

Самое раннее употребление в Русском национальном корпусе относится к 1783 году, так что этот термин не изобретение советской бюрократии:

> Превеликое употребление мяса, нужное англичанам, и великий вывоз соленого мяса, коровьего масла, сыру и т. п. доказывают, на каком степени процветения должно быть там скотоводство крупного рогатого скота. [Н. И. Новиков. О торговле вообще (1783)]

---

В ["Словаре Брокгауза и Ефрона" (1907)](http://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%A1%D0%91%D0%95/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) сказано следующее:

> **Скот рогатый крупный**. — Такое название издавна усвоено виду рода Bos — В. taurus, т. е. нашему быку и корове. Другие виды этого рода также крупны и рогаты, но их обыкновенно называют своими именами. Так, В. bubalus называется буйволом, В. Bison в Америке бизоном, а у нас зубром и т. д. И из других домашних животных также рогаты овцы, но их так и называют овцами, а не **рогатым скотом**.

Из чего можно сделать вывод что быков и коров могли называть и просто *рогатым скотом* (без слова "крупный", которое, кстати в корпусе иногда заменяется на "большой"). Поиск в корпусе дает следующие цитаты:

> Пифагор за изобретение одного геометрического правила Зевесу принёс на жертву сто **волов**. Но ежели бы за найденные в нынешние времена от остроумных математиков правила по суеверной его ревности поступать, то бы едва в целом свете столько **рогатого скота** сыскалось.  [М. В. Ломоносов. Волфианская экспериментальная физика, с немецкого подлинника на латинском языке сокращенная (1745)]
>
> Весною ж **рогатый скот** чесать железными скребницами и при том мыть в реке, чрез что грязь и плоть и линючая шерсть вытти может; сие для скота весьма здорово. [В. Н. Татищев. Краткие экономические до деревни следующие записки (1742)]

---

In some Russian dialects there is a word **говядо** that exactly matches English word cattle (cows, bulls and oxen). However this word is not widely used in Russian nowadays. The **Крупный рогатый скот** term, however is used for at least 220 years. Though it can also mean many other animals like yaks or bisons, in fact these animals are not used in Russia, so *крупный рогатый скот* means exactly cows, bulls and oxen.

Comment: Никто ведь и не утверждал, что это термин _советской_ бюрократии. Бюрократия существовала задолго до образования СССР.

Comment: @RomanPetrenko Думаю что во времена Ломоносова бюрократов не было, а если и были то им было не до "поголовья крупного рогатого скота". Во всяком случае они бы не стали изобретать длинные наукообразные термины (как например "дорожно-транспортное проишествие" вместо "авария" ), а воспользовались существующими.

Comment: Во времена Ломоносова бюрократия была, да ещё какая. Насчет длинных слов, "действительный статский советник" - как вам?

Comment: @Anixx Должность должна звучать солидно. А вот назвать лопату и ящик с песком "средствами пожаротушения" - это как раз изобретение бюрократии, позволяющее замаскировать их под огнетушители. В случае быков+коров использование абстрактного "крупного рогатого скота" с точки зрения бюрократии никаких преимуществ вообще не дает, т.к. других животных, попадающих в эту категорию не используют и замаскировать козу под корову не удается.

Answer (score 7):

Officially, the term *корова* is being used to identify a cow which already had calved. *Бык* means non-castrated bull. There are also several more terms to describe cows and bulls (information from [Russian Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82)):

- *Волы* — bulls of three years and older which have been castrated at an
  early age;
- *Бычки* — bulls aged between three months and three years;
- *Бычки-кастраты* — castrated bulls under three years;
- *Телята молочные* — cows and bulls under three months fed on milk;
- *Тёлки* — cows never calved;
- *Нетели* — cows inseminated artifically;

There is just no short term to designate all representatives of this species. All these terms can be combined as "крупный рогатый скот". In colloquial speech, the words *корова* and *бык* are enough to describe any of them (considering gender, of course), but when it comes to official documentation, there is a need in a more general denomination.

Comment: Why there is no short term single word noun for "Крупный рогатый скот" like "лошади", "куры", "овцы" etc.? Or why there's no "Мелкий рогатый скот" or "крупный парнокопытный скот с рылами"?

Comment: @Vi. About "Мелкий рогатый скот": there _is_ such [term](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82). It unites goats and sheep.

Comment: @RomanPetrenko Are there other specimens of КПС except of cows (bulls/etc.)? It looks like a collective term like "мелкий рогатый скот", but I don't know any other genera (not cows) to belong into "крупный рогатый скот" group.

Comment: @Vi. yes there are (see my answer) - bisons and yaks for example.

Comment: @SergeyKirienko I see now.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is just the difference between normal speech and the bureaucratic style of official documents and speeches.  Consider the following:

> население vs. люди
>
> проживать vs. жить
>
> продукты питания vs. еда или пища
>
> место жительства vs. дом или адрес

Comment: Official documents can't use term "корова" just because officially, "корова" means _not any_ cow, but **only** cow that calves. There is just no short term to designate all representatives of this species.

Answer (score 1):

Because КРС is not only cows, but also зубры, бизоны, буйволы, яки and овцебыки (thought formally last are not Bovinae but Ovibos).

Simple word for КРС in Polish, I believe, is *bydło*.